# Ruby on Rails: how to render a view from same controller but with a different route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller, `farms_controller`, that is being used for two different routes, `farms` and `person_farms`; the two routes use the same folder for view templates (i.e., `new_person_farm_path` and `new_farm_path` use the same template, `new.html.erb`). I want to access the farms register pages both separately and inside the person register, where some functionalities are different using the URL in some tests to show different functionalities (via `request.env['PATH_INFO'].include? 'person_farms'`, because I don't know a best way).

When I submit without the required fields (name) from the `new_person_farm_path`, the create function renders the `new_farm_path` page with a different styling for incorrect fields (using the 'twitter-bootstrap-rails' gem). I want it to instead render the `new_person_farm_path` page, with the same template file but a different routing (different URL). I tried to use `redirect_to` and it shows the page in the correct URL, but not the styling in the wrong fields.

However, all the instructions I saw in [Rails documentation for rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) are above rendering a specific file, but it's not what I need. I have a feeling that it's not the "Rails way", but I'm a starter on RoR and this a legacy system that is being rewritten to Rails, so I can't correct the DB logic for now.

So, is there a way to render a view from same controller but with a different route?

---

My code:

```
def create
  @farm = Farm.new(farm_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @farm.save
      # Param sent by the page to test if I'm in a person_farms page
      # instead of a farms page because the request.env test doesn't work here.
      # I feel that this is not the correct way to do that, but I can leave the correct way to another question.
      # However, if someone has a suggestion a comment would be appreciated.
      if params[:is_person_farm_page]
        format.html { redirect_to @person_farm_path(@farm), notice: 'Farm saved' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @farm }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @farm, notice: 'Farm saved' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @farm }
      end
    else
      #This is the point where I want to redirect to new_person_farm_path
      #I would need to test using the params[:is_person_farm_page] above
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Send parameters in the path like:

```
new_person_farm_path(param_1: 'my param')
```

And then in the controller you can access that value with:

```
params[:param_1]
```

And pass it to your view as an instance variable or (if you are using) a view object:

```
@show_some_part = params[:param_1].present? # This can be a boolean or something else
```

Now in your view you can ask for that value

```
<%= something if @show_some_part %>
```

Comment: So, instead of using two different routes, I should use the same route (and so the same URL) but every time I call a path from the controller, I could pass a parameter and so it'll know that I'm in a person_farms page or in farms page, that's right?

Answer (score 0):

For solving my specific problem (redirect to the correct `new` page but with the error fields), I did this solution (probably not the best if you are doing it from the start, but I was already with many functionalities working, and I wanted to keep the `person_farm_path` and `farm_path` as different URLs):

In my controller, I used the first answer to this thread: [Rails: I cant pass a validation error in a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368717/rails-i-cant-pass-a-validation-error-in-a-redirect), and so I inserted this code in the `create` action:

```
if @farm.save
  ... #the same code in my question
else
  if params[:is_person_farm_page]
    #pass the errors messages via flash, "imploding" the array of errors into a string
    format.html { redirect_to new_person_farm_path, :flash => { :error => flash_errors = @farm.errors.full_messages.join(',')}}
    format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @farm.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Now I'm able to pass the errors through the redirect action, instead of the render action.
Then, in the `form.html.erb`, I only need do "explode" the string sent in a new array:

```
<% errors_sent_via_flask = flash[:error] ? flash[:error].split(",") : [] %>
```

For seeing all the errors_message I can get, I used `<%= errors_sent_via_flask .inspect %>` (this echoes all array members in the page) and simulated the error situation and submitted the form. For example, the error message for a missing name field is something like "Farm name can't be blank".

Now I can check if the "Farm name can't be blank" error is happening using `errors_sent_via_flask.include? "Farm name can't be blank"` in the page.